# UIScrollView as image viewer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to use UIScrollView as image viewer like Photo app. The UIScrollView is supposed to show photos with swiping, zooming and rotating with interface rotation.i have to load minimum 20 images.is it possible? which is the best way? plz post some sample codes.

Comment: This is a _very_ general question - you're dealing with multiple concepts (swiping, zooming, interface rotation) and haven't provided sample code of what you've tried or a place to get started. Try to focus in on one area, or take a stab at it (using Apple-provided sample code (the Scrolling project would be a good start)) and then refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple and easy to use photo browser called MWPhotoBrowser which you should be able to look at and dissect.

It is an implementation of a photo viewer that I wrote allowing the user to view one or more images in a similar way to the native Photos app. It can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, file paths to images on the device, or URLs images online. Photos can also be zoomed, panned, and navigated with previous/next buttons.

[View MWPhotoBrowser on GitHub](http://bit.ly/mwphotobrowser)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the sample application page control here https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/ , it should help you get started, they have a scroll view that you can use to scroll through a bunch of pages, you can modify this to do pictures.  It doesnt do zooming o rotationg but its a good place to start